# jQuery disable multiple options by value

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to know how to disable multiple options by value. I know I can do this by:

```
<script>
$('option[value=1],option[value=2]...').prop('disabled', true);
</script>
```

but I have about 100+ values and there is no particular pattern for the values.

What is the shortest way to do this, if there is?

Comment: Depends on your actual HTML and the values. There are many jQuery selectors (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You should find one that matches as many elements as possible.

Comment: Do you have a list of all the values to disable? or is it all of them?

Comment: @simcha khabinsky I have 100+ random values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var values = [5, 4, 3];

$.each(values, function(k, v) {
     $('option[value=' + v + ']').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9ENQX/)**

Answer (score 0):

A loop may be?

```
var startingNumber = 1, endingNumber = 100;
for(var i = startingNumber; i < endingNumber +1 ; i++){
   $('option[value="'+ i + '"]').prop('disabled',true); 
}
```

Or fill an array and loop through it:

```
var nums = [1,2,3,5,8];
for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    $('option[value="'+ i + '"]').prop('disabled',true);    
}
```

Comment: this is true if the values to be selected are 1 to 100 but im trying to select random numbers

Comment: @Bernie I answered this when you hadn't edited your question. Your question was unclear and you had 1,2 as your example. What do you think I should've assumed?

Comment: That's why I up voted it, I know the question was not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

@martynas has a good answer , but this one is even shorter:

```
var disabledValuesArr = [5, 4, 3];
$("option[value='" + disabledValuesArr.join("'],[value='") + "']").prop('disabled', true);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xT8u/)